# Can Content Delivery Web service work with content published to a file system, rather than a database?

Tags: content-delivery, odata

I have few questions related to Content Delivery Web service:

1. Will Content Delivery web service work if the content is published to a file system, and not to a broker database?
2. If it does, how should request be sent to fetch the data ?
3. What configuration settings needs to be changed if we want to get the data from File system using the web service ?

Answer (score 4):

No, the content has to come from the database.

It may be that you have local file system binaries or links to urls in your webservice content.
In the event that you do, you can manage this via configuring the cd_link_conf.xml file, this allows you to add a domain, protocol and port to any links/paths stored in the db content.

So you're perfectly able to to share content with external websites/applications, but the published content must come from the broker db.

If you do have content published to the file system, it's also possible to set up a new publishing target that stores the same content into a broker database.

Answer (score 1):

1. No - The CD Web Service will only serve content stored in the Database.
2. Not applicable.
3. Not applicable.